# Generalized formula (number theory)

Tags: number-theory

How can I choose a generalized formula that converts a number to it's superior multiple of 4?
For example, if we have a number of the form 
$4k+r$, where $r\in {1, 2, 3}$, it will be converted to $4k+4$, but if we have a nr of the form $4k$ it will stay the same.
I hope you could help me!

Answer (score 2):

Often, we exploit the floor and ceiling functions for such things:

$$ 4 \lceil n/4 \rceil $$

Comment: Works for non integers, too

Answer (score 0):

Required number is $n - (n\mod 4) + 4$

Comment: Assuming by "$n \bmod 4$" you mean to give the remainder in the interval $[0,3]$, this formula incorrectly gives $n+4$ when $n$ is a multiple of 4.

Comment: @Hurkyl convert 0 to 4 and then it works 0 is simply the typical representative of the equivalence class.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee: If we're using nonstandard representatives, then $n - (n \bmod 4)$ works if you pick representatives in $[-3,0]$.